# How to get index of select option value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the index of an event but the index is not set yet

```
<selectonChange= {(event)=> {
    if (props.eSimStore.examMode != 'read') {
      if (event.target.value) {
        props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index));
      }
    }
  }
}> {props.eSimStore.question.options.map((option, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={index}>
        {htmlToReactParser.parse(option)}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Here, I want to set the index of value in `props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index))`, but in `onChange()` method value is set as event but i want to set the index of value. please someone help me how to get the index.

Comment: I want to set the index of value in `props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index))`, but in onChange() method value is set as event but i want to set the index of value. please someone help me how to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `event.target.value` is what you need.

Try replacing this part

```
if (event.target.value) {
    props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index));
}
```

with this

```
props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + event.target.value));
```

Note: I removed `if` as you see, which I guess will make more sense when `event.target.value` is 0, which is falsey. You may keep it though depending on your values.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not getting the index. i need to get the index of value.

Comment: i need the index of `(event.target.value)`. `(event.target.value)` returns the value of option but i need the index of value.

Comment: @M.Mahmud You assigned `index` to the `value` attributes of the `<option>` elements. So, `event.target.value` gives you that value, which is index of the option. Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes i tried but it did not give the index, i tried many time. as far i know `event.target.value` return the value of option field not the `value` attribute.

Comment: yes i get the index but it `(String.fromCharCode(65 + index)` should return A for index 0 right? but it returns some unwanted index.
please help me to find out this issue

Comment: @M.Mahmud Yes, it gives you 'A'. What's the unwanted index you've telling? Can you give an example?

Comment: but its not giving me 'A' . it is giving me some gurbage value like
'^' for other option it gives me 'M', 'v' etc.

Comment: i solve this issue. previously it returns index as string so i convert it to number `let index= +event.target.value` and now it shows correct answer.
Thanks a lot @Emre Erdogen. without your help i can't come out this issue

Comment: @Erdogen can you please help me another issue i am facing trouble. I have already asked question about that issue and here is the link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016451/conditionally-selected-is-not-triggered-select-onchangeevent-method-in-reactjs)