# Conditionally Selected is not triggered select onChange(event) method in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to select an option when showAnswer flag is true and the option is selected if it is answer.But the problem is the option is show on select field but `onChange(event)` is not triggered and it is not set as state.

```
<select  onChange={(event) => { if (props.eSimStore.examMode != 'read') {
                                           let index= +event.target.value;
                                           props.setNewAnswer(String.fromCharCode(65 + index));
                                   }

                }} >  {props.eSimStore.question.options.map((option, index) => (
                               <option
                                        key = {index}
                                        selected={
                                            (props.eSimStore.showAnswerFlag && String.fromCharCode(65 + index) ==
                                                props.eSimStore.question.answer)
                                        }
                                value = {index}
                                    >
                                    {htmlToReactParser.parse(option)}
                                    </option> </select>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mahmud-hasan-menon/pen/XGNQzK) in here i only use the functional component where i am facing trouble.

Comment: in option field i use selected attribute to select a option conditionally `selected={
                                            (props.eSimStore.showAnswerFlag && String.fromCharCode(65 + index) ==
                                                props.eSimStore.question.answer)
                                        }`

Comment: Can you please share codepen. Its hard to get solution of react problems like this

Comment: i tried but in my project there are lots of file need to add because it use redux. my concern is why selected is not set as event

Comment: I couldn't see your using onChange on <select>  it should be inside the tag like this
`<select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>` and writing onChange like this better write a function wrapper bind that and let that wrapper return the html.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mahmud-hasan-menon/pen/XGNQzK)

Comment: i use functional component in here and also redux ,also my other component is build like this which i added in [codepen](https://codepen.io/mahmud-hasan-menon/pen/XGNQzK)

Comment: Codepen not working i guess you need to include react dependency or cdn their.

Comment: you can't see anything or output?? i only use the one file where select field is used in Codepen

Comment: @somsgod in my project i have lots of field beside i use redux for state change, there are also lots of file. so in codepen i only use the functional component where select field is rendered. so you can not see the output